Friends Episode Identification
I have been wondering this for a while, but as much as I try, I can't seem to find the answer. I really would appreciate if someone could tell me what episode of the tv show Friends this snippet is from. The snippet is at 2:51 in this YouTube video:




If you mean the bit where Phoebe has those pink fuzzy scrunchies, it's a scene from the season 8 episode The One with the Birthing Video where Phoebe says:

I know you’ve been really depressed lately, so I brought someone over to cheer you up. Right outside this door is a real, live, furry playmate.

Joey's depressed because of his crush on Rachel, so Phoebe brought him a dog to cheer him up. Here's a clip from the episode where Ross gives Phoebe taffy and she's wearing the same outfit:



I can't believe I know this. Not a good sign... ;)
